# GoogleMap with AppCompatActivity class

Tags: android, google-maps, appcompatactivity

I am using AppCompatActivity extended class with google Map i have the below code with the class and on create method

```html
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainHistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener,OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_history);
          


SupportMapFragment mapFragment =(SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

     @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;

            // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        }
```

The code fails with below error

```html
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.dbprox.selfpatrol, PID: 14938
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dbprox.selfpatrol/com.dbprox.selfpatrol.MainHistoryActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2380)
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2432)
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345)
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5347)
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:835)
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.dbprox.selfpatrol.MainHistoryActivity.onCreate(MainHistoryActivity.java:59)
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5360)
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2334)
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2432) 
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345) 
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5347) 
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:835) 
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651) 
04-19 00:16:00.719 14938-14938/com.dbprox.selfpatrol E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have following dependencies declared in build.gradle

```html
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

Comment: show your activity_main_history.xml file

Comment: having the same problem do you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Basically  [`NullPointerException`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) or `Unable to start activity` occurs when there is issue in `onCreate()` method of activity. This error occurs when we change any xml values of layout related to this activity, if we do not map xml UI's properly in our activity and lastly, try to access UI which is in another layout file. Do check all the mapped elements and give a unique name. Check the value of your content view declaration and mapFragment.